# parse server certificate issue

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

So my company has setup their own parse server. I am able to connect to the server but if i try to run this below code, i get certificate invalid error.

```
        let menu = PFObject(className: "MENU")
        menu.setObject(menuMain, forKey: "MAIN_MANU")
        menu.setObject(menuSub, forKey: "SUB_MENU")
        menu.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (succeeded, error) -> Void in
            if succeeded {
                print("Object Uploaded")
            } else {
                print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

Error -

NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “dev.example.com” which could put your confidential information at risk., 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://dev.example.com/parse/classes/MENU, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dev.example.com/parse/classes/MENU, NSErrorClientCertificateStateKey=0}]

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I edited your question to use example.com instead of xxx.com so you were not linking to inappropriate content

Answer (score 0):

[Info here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2232/_index.html)

With just the info you posted, it looks like the server you are connecting to does not have its TLS certificate set up correctly. It's probably for the wrong domain or the wrong subdomain (maybe the certificate is for `www.` but you are connecting to `dev.`) You can change your app settings to support insecure connections but you should probably just get the server fixed.

Comment: Is there any work around? unfortunately i can't get the server team to fix this from their side. Is there any way we fix this issue from our side ?